# Using Hash Tables in Leu of Multidimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash, neural-network

**EDIT:** Found a solution! Like the commenters suggested, using `memset` is an insanely better approach. Replace the entire for loop with

`memset(lookup->n, -3, (dimensions*sizeof(signed char)));`

where

`long int dimensions = box1 * box2 * box3 * box4 * box5 * box6 * box7 * box8 * memvara * memvarb * memvarc * memvard * adirect * tdirect * fs * bs * outputnum;`

## Intro

Right now, I'm looking at a beast of a for-loop:

```
    for (j = 0;j < box1; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < box2; k++)
            {
                for (l = 0; l < box3; l++)
                {
                    for (m = 0; m < box4; m++)
                    {
                        for (x = 0;x < box5; x++)
                        {
                            for (y = 0; y < box6; y++)
                            {
                                for (xa = 0;xa < box7; xa++)
                                {
                                    for (xb = 0; xb < box8; xb++)
                                    {
                                        for (nb = 0; nb < memvara; nb++)
                                        {
                                            for (na = 0; na < memvarb; na++)
                                            {
                                                for (nx = 0; nx < memvarc; nx++)
                                                {
                                                    for (nx1 = 0; nx1 < memvard; nx1++)
                                                    {
                                                        for (naa = 0; naa < adirect; naa++)
                                                        {
                                                            for (nbb = 0; nbb < tdirect; nbb++)
                                                            {
                                                                for (ncc = 0; ncc < fs; ncc++)
                                                                {
                                                                    for (ndd = 0; ndd < bs; ndd++)
                                                                    {
                                                                        for (o = 0; o < outputnum; o++)
                                                                        {
                                                                            lookup->n[j][k][l][m][x][y][xa][xb][nb][na][nx][nx1][naa][nbb][ncc][ndd][o] = -3;     //set to default value

                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

## The Problem

This loop is called every cycle in the main run to reset values to an initial state. Unfortunately, it is necessary for the structure of the program that this many values are kept in a single data structure.

Here's the kicker: for every 60 seconds of program run time, **57 seconds goes to this function alone**.

## The Question

My question is this: would hash tables be an appropriate substitute for a linear array? This array has an O(n^17) cardinality, yet hash tables have an ideal of O(1).

- If so, what hash library would you recommend? This program is in C and has no native hash support.
- If not, what would you recommend instead?
- Can you provide some pseudo-code on how you think this should be implemented?

## Notes

1. OpenMP was used in an attempt to parallelize this loop. Numerous implementations only resulted in slightly-to-greatly increased run time.
2. Memory usage is not particularly an issue -- this program is intended to be ran on an insanely high-spec'd computer.
3. We are student researchers, thrust into a heretofore unknown world of optimization and parallelization -- please bear with us, and thank you for any help

Comment: No sane programmer can look at this code and not question why it needs to be done this way in the first place. So probably best if you head that off and tell us the actual context of the code.

Comment: "would hash tables be an appropriate substitute for a linear array?". And nobody can answer that question anyway without knowing the actual problem being solved by the code.

Comment: Are these *actually* arrays, or pointer-to-pointers? It's not clear from your code (the syntax is the same either way). If it's arrays, indexing is O(1) as well, so a hash-map doesn't help.

Comment: Was the array allocated as a single contiguous block of memory? If so, there are much more efficient ways to clear it.

Comment: Please explain what you are actually using this for in context. Code like this is a huge red-flag and can probably be expressed better in a different way. Also, look up [`memset()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) as it may be appropriate.

Comment: @AlanAu This is code inherited from my professor. It's a very large neural network project, and this is one of the fundamental blocks of it. It stores integer values representing states of neurons. They are reset to a matrix containing what our program interprets as 'null' every generation (-3), and single values are read/wrote to at various stages of the program.

Comment: @EOF The above code is the bulk of a function called `compile_tablemain`, which has a pointer `calookup *lookup` in the function parameters. `compile_tablemain(&(t->tissues[i]),r,s)` is called from another function `evaluatepopulation(...,calookup *r,...)` which is called from main as with the declaration of the array, `calookup ra`

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, it was. What would you recommend? Iskar, I will do that and report back, thank you

Comment: If it is a contiguous block, and you want to clear it, use `memset()`.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston That depends on a couple of other missing pieces of information. Adding the structure definition to the question will supply the first piece of information, which is the type of the objects in the array. The second piece of information is, "Why -3?". Is it possible to offset all of the values so that `0` is the default?

Comment: Why not use caffe, torch or theano, which are well known open source packages that implement neural networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hash vs Array

As comments have specified, an array should not be a problem here.  Lookup into an array with a known offset is **O(1)**.

## The Bottleneck

It seems to me that the bulk of the work here (and the reason it is slow) is the number of pointer de-references in the inner-loop.

To explain in a bit more detail, consider `myData[x][y][z]` in the following code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < someVal1; x++) {
   for (int y = 0; y < someVal2; y++) {
      for (int z = 0; z < someVal3; z++) {
         myData[x][y][z] = -3; // x and y only change in outer-loops.
      }
   }
}
```

To compute the location for the `-3`, we do a lookup and add a value - once for `myData[x]`, then again to get to `myData[x][y]`, and once more finally for `myData[x][y][z]`.

Since this lookup is in the inner-most portion of the loop, we have redundant reads.  `myData[x]` and `myData[x][y]` are being recomputed, even when only `z`'s value is changing.  The lookups were performed during a previous iteration, but the results weren't stored.

For *your* loop, there are **many** layers of lookups being computed each iteration, even when only the value of `o` is changing in that inner-loop.

## An Improvement for the Bottleneck

To make one lookup, per loop iteration, per loop level, simply store intermediate lookups.  Using `int*` as the indirection (though any type would work here), the sample code above (with `myData`) would become:

```
int **a, *b;
for (int x = 0; x < someVal1; x++) {
   a = myData[x]; // Store the lookup.
   for (int y = 0; y < someVal2; y++) {
      b = a[y]; // Indirection based on the stored lookup.
      for (int z = 0; z < someVal3; z++) {
         b[z] = -3; // This can be extrapolated as needed to deeper levels.
      }
   }
}
```

This is just sample code, small adjustments may be necessary to get it to compile (casts and so forth).  Note that there is probably no advantage to using this approach with a 3-dimensional array.  However, for a 17-dimensional large data set with simple inner-loop operations (such as assignment), this approach should help quite a bit.

Finally, I'm assuming you aren't actually just assigning the value of `-3`.  You can use `memset` to accomplish that goal much more efficiently.

Comment: This is a fantastic and lucid explanation Steven -- thank you very much! I will try implementation immediately and let you know.

Comment: This principle helped me solve a completely unrelated issue that had a similar behavior. Minimize your lookups!